# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null - some of the code work

Tags: javascript, php, getelementbyid

I want to read the user's choice by the function:

```
var e = document.getElementById("Trip_Type");
var Trip_Type = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var i = document.getElementById("Trip_Population");
var Trip_Population= i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
var j = document.getElementById("Trip_Duration");
var Trip_Duration= j.options[j.selectedIndex].value;
```

The option `Trip_Population` and `Trip_type` is varchar and chosen from a drop down list:

```
<select id = "Trip_Population" style="width: 120px">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

The `Trip_Duration` is float and chosen from free text input:

```
<input name="Trip_Duration" style="width: 117px" type="text"></strong></td>
```

After submitting the information I want a pop-up window with transferring information to the next page:

```
var myWindow = window.open("Tripdet.php?Trip_Type="+Trip_Type+"&Trip_Population="+Trip_Population+"&Trip_Duration="+Trip_Duration, "", "width=400, height=200");
```

The pop-up is not showing up and I receive an error on the console on the `Trip_Duration` (if I remove it from the code it's working):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Comment: For an input, you want the value, not the options.

Comment: So why this code is not working?  `<input name="Trip_Duration" style="width: 117px" type="text"></strong></td>`

Comment: Your `Trip_Duration` element does not have an ID, hence `getElementById()` will not find anything. See the below answer for why it still won't work after you fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input tag does not have options. Just retrieve the value:

```
var Trip_Duration= j.value;
```

and as Phil pointed out, input is missing id

```
<input id="Trip_Duration" name="Trip_Duration" style="width: 117px" type="text">
```

Comment: The element also needs an ID ~ `<input name="Trip_Duration" id="Trip_Duration" ...>`